# Check existing Data in Listview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

listview: `lvData`

```
    acctcode     first      last

1    DFNTN       High       Definition
2    BLNCE       World      Balance 
3    RNBOW       Rain       Bow
```

I want to add data in `lvData` using `textbox`. But first the program must check if the data provided in `textbox` already exists. Based on the `acctcode` column.

here is my code:

```
 Dim articlecheck As String = TEXTBOX.text
        Dim founditem As ListViewItem = LVDATA.FindItemWithText(articlecheck)
        If Not (founditem Is Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data already exists!", "Duplicate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        Else
          'ADD DATA in the LISTVIEW'
```

The problem is If I put value in textbox with something like this: `DFN`, `BLN`, `RNB`. My program will still show `"Data alrleady exist!"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the same FindItemWithText method with these parameters.

```
 LVDATA.FindItemWithText(articlecheck,False,0,False)
```

Comment: Thank you @Abdul. it works. care to explain what does adding false,0,false do?

Comment: the first False is passed to ignore text starts with search, and 0 is for starting index of the search text , and last one is to negate the prefixsearch

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop trough subitems, because `FindItemWithText` will search for text in all subitems:

There is code :

```
Private Function FindSubItem(ByVal lv As ListView, ByVal SearchString As String) As Boolean
    'find column index in listview by name "acctcode"
    Dim idx = (From c In ListView1.Columns Where c.Text = "acctcode" Select c = c.Index).First()
    For Each itm As ListViewItem In lv.Items
        'search only subitems of column "acctcode"
        If itm.SubItems(idx).Text = SearchString Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

and then use :

```
Dim articlecheck As String = TEXTBOX.text
    If FindSubItem(LVDATA, articlecheck) = True Then
      MessageBox.Show("Data already exists!", "Duplicate", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
      Exit Sub
    Else
      'add Your item
    End If
```